# Returning random element from a Python array based on search criteria

Tags: python, arrays, search, indices

Apologies if this is straightforward, but I've been looking for a little while now and can't find a simple, efficient solution.

I have a two-dimensional Python list of lists which only consists of 1's and 0's.

e.g.:

```
a=[[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]]
```

I wish to return, at random, the indices of a random element which is = 1.  In this case I would like to return either:

```
[0,1], [1,1], [1,2], [2,0], or [2,2]
```

with an equal probability.

I could iterate through every element in the structure and compile a list of eligible indices and then choose one at random using random.choice(list) - but this seems very slow and I can't help feeling there is a neater, more Pythonic way to approach this.  I will be doing this for probably a 20x20 array and will need to do it many times, so I could do with it being as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

Comment: Are you sure you have an array? Or is it a list of lists?

Comment: does "many times" refer to doing it on the same array many times, or for different arrays?

Comment: Sorry, list of lists.  My mistake.  I'll correct the post.

Comment: I will need to do it to the same array many times, but the elements in the array won't be static.  Every so often some values of elements will flip.

Comment: Is "array" static (you mention `a 20x20 array`)? If so, you could generate your possibilities once and keep using that list as input to your random.

Comment: then it seems best to store the elements which are '1's instead, and update those; well, without knowledge of what this data structure needs to be used for, it's going to be very vague. What operations need to be fast?

Comment: I think if you want to really do this efficiently (without making a new list of candidates every time or choosing random items until you find one that works) then you need a different data structure. A  tree that knows which of it's subtrees have valid elements for example.

Comment: How is it random if it's based on search criteria? Sounds like a contradiction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension to generate a list of tuples (positions of 1), then random.choice :

```
from random import choice

a = [[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]]
mylist = []

[[mylist.append((i,j)) for j, x in enumerate(v) if x == 1] for i, v in enumerate(a)]
print(choice(mylist))
```

Comment: That looks absolutely the perfect answer I was looking for, thanks!  I was trying to think of something along those lines but my Python just wasn't quite up to it.

Comment: @Scott, welcome to StackOverflow! Just noticed that you seemed to like this answer.  One of the cool things about StackOverflow is that it's self-improving if everyone uses it correctly: the best answers get "Chosen" and voted up.  If you like this one it not only rewards the answerer, but also improves the site if you vote good answers up, and accept your favorite answer to your questions.

Comment: @Cpfohl - I just registered and tried, but it says I need at least 15 reputation.  I guess this is because I'm a newbie, but I would vote up if I could!

Comment: @Scott:  You can "accept" one of the answers -- the answer that in your opinion answers the question best.  Just click the check mark next to that answer.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for participating!  Hope S.O. is helpful to you.  P.S. You'll gain 2 rep. for accepting answers and 5 points for asking a good question that gets voted up. Two good questions, and accepting 3 answers will get you to 15 in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array to achieve this:

```
from numpy import array
random_index = tuple(random.choice(array(array(a).nonzero()).T))
```

If your store your data in NumPy arrays right from the beginning, this approach will probably be faster than anything you can do with a list of lists.

If you want do choose many indices for the same data, there are even faster approaches.

Answer (score 1):

[`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) allow us to pick an element at random from a list, so we just need to use a list comprehension to create a list of the indexes where the elements are 1 and then pick one at random.

We can use the follow list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]]
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(len(a)) for y in range(len(a[x])) if a[x][y] == 1]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
```

Which means we can do:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([(x,y) for x in range(len(a)) for y in range(len(a[x])) if a[x][y] == 1])
(1, 1)
```

If you will be doing this many times it may be worth caching the list of indexes generated by the comprehension and then picking from it several times, rather than calculating the list comprehension every single time.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your result from random.choice check if it is how you would like it with the correct elements if it is not random again

```
def return_random(li):
    item = random.choice(li)
    if item == 1: #insert check here
        return item
    else:
        return_random(li)
```

Edit: to avoid confusion with re module, thanks

Comment: Should not use well used `re` as variable. It can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful and I hadn't considering doing it that way.  One potential problem is that at times the lists might be quite sparsely populated with 1's, in which case this method might be very inefficient.  But I can certainly give it a try as I won't know if this is a problem until I actually run the code and see.

Comment: Worry about optimisation later. You can always optimise a working program but its difficult to speed up come that doesn't actually process

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to store the data in a completely different way:  Instead of a list of lists, use a set of index pairs representing the entries that are 1.  In your example, this would be

```
s = set((0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2))
```

To randomly choose an index pair, use

```
random.choice(list(s))
```

To set an entry to 1, use

```
s.add((i, j))
```

To set an entry to 0, use

```
s.remove((i, j))
```

To flip an entry, use

```
s.symmetric_difference_update([(i, j)])
```

To check if an entry is 1, use

```
(i, j) in s
```